# JAXB unmarshalling from XmlStreamReader results in null object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, xmlstreamreader

I created a Java procedure for unmarshalling an XML message where a "startTag" can be provided to start unmarshalling at a particular element within the message. I used an `XMLStreamReader` to make this selection.

A complete copy-pastable demo of the problem I run into is below. The 'xml' message is what I need to work with. It unfortunately yields a `null` car object in the result, while the 'xmlStripped' message yields a fully unmarshalled result.

I isolated the problem to the `xmlns="http://www.example.com/type"` namespace in the `<response>` element. When I remove this, the 'xml' is properly unmarshalled.

I have **no control** over the XML. The 'xml' variable is what I need to work with. I have **little** control over the XSD/`ObjectFactory`, so my first course of action is to look for a solution in the unmarshalling procedure.

Please let me know if you know why this fails and if you have a solution. Thanks!

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class XmlStreamReaderUnmarshallingTest {

    private static JAXBContext jaxbContext;

    static {
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n" +
            "\txmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" \n" +
            "\txmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">\n" +
            "\t<soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "\t\t<response xmlns=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t<type:serviceResponse xmlns:type=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t<Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t<Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Brand>Mitsubishi</Brand>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Color>Red</Color>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t</Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t</Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t</type:serviceResponse>\n" +
            "\t\t</response>\n" +
            "\t</soapenv:Body>\n" +
            "</soapenv:Envelope>";


    private static String xmlStripped = "<type:serviceResponse xmlns:type=\"http://www.example.com/type\">\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t<Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t<Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Brand>Mitsubishi</Brand>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t\t<Color>Red</Color>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t\t</Car>\n" +
            "\t\t\t\t</Body>\n" +
            "\t\t\t</type:serviceResponse>";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
        readXml(xml, "serviceResponse");
        readXml(xmlStripped, "serviceResponse");
    }

    private static void readXml(String inputXml, String startFromElement) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {

        final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        final Reader reader = new StringReader(inputXml);
        final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
        final XMLStreamReader streamReader = skipToElement(xmlStreamReader, startFromElement);
        final MyServiceResponse serviceResponse = (MyServiceResponse) unmarshal(streamReader);

        if(serviceResponse.getBody().getCar() == null) {
            System.out.println("It didn't work :-(");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It worked");
        }
    }

    private static XMLStreamReader skipToElement(final XMLStreamReader xsr, final String startAtElement) throws XMLStreamException {
        while (startAtElement != null && xsr.hasNext()) {
            xsr.next();
            if (xsr.hasName()) {
                final String name = xsr.getName().getLocalPart();
                if (name.equals(startAtElement)) {
                    return xsr;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Could not find element %s in response", startAtElement));
    }

    private static Object unmarshal(final XMLStreamReader xsr) throws JAXBException {
        final Object entity = unmarshaller(jaxbContext).unmarshal(xsr);
        return (entity instanceof JAXBElement ? ((JAXBElement) entity).getValue() : entity);
    }

    // Create unmarshaller every time
    private static Unmarshaller unmarshaller(JAXBContext context) throws JAXBException {

        return context.createUnmarshaller();

    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MyServiceResponse", propOrder = {

})
class MyServiceResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Body")
    protected MyServiceResponse.Body body;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the body property.
     *
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the body property.
     *
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public void setBody(MyServiceResponse.Body value) {
        this.body = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     *
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     *
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType&gt;
     *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *       &lt;all&gt;
     *         &lt;element name="Car" minOccurs="0"&gt;
     *           &lt;complexType&gt;
     *             &lt;complexContent&gt;
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
     *                 &lt;all&gt;
     *                   &lt;element name="Brand" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *                   &lt;element name="Color" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
     *                 &lt;/all&gt;
     *               &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *             &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     *           &lt;/complexType&gt;
     *         &lt;/element&gt;
     *       &lt;/all&gt;
     *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
     *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
     * &lt;/complexType&gt;
     * </pre>
     *
     *
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

    })
    public static class Body {

        @XmlElement(name = "Car")
        protected MyServiceResponse.Body.Car car;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the car property.
         *
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
         *
         */
        public MyServiceResponse.Body.Car getCar() {
            return car;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the car property.
         *
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
         *
         */
        public void setCar(MyServiceResponse.Body.Car value) {
            this.car = value;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         *
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         *
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType&gt;
         *   &lt;complexContent&gt;
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType"&gt;
         *       &lt;all&gt;
         *         &lt;element name="Brand" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
         *         &lt;element name="Color" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/&gt;
         *       &lt;/all&gt;
         *     &lt;/restriction&gt;
         *   &lt;/complexContent&gt;
         * &lt;/complexType&gt;
         * </pre>
         *
         *
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {

        })
        public static class Car {

            @XmlElement(name = "Brand")
            protected String brand;
            @XmlElement(name = "Color")
            protected String color;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the brand property.
             *
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public String getBrand() {
                return brand;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the brand property.
             *
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public void setBrand(String value) {
                this.brand = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the color property.
             *
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public String getColor() {
                return color;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the color property.
             *
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *
             */
            public void setColor(String value) {
                this.color = value;
            }

        }

    }

}


@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _ServiceResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.com/type", "serviceResponse");

    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.example.type
     *
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse createMyServiceResponse() {
        return new MyServiceResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse.Body }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body createMyServiceResponseBody() {
        return new MyServiceResponse.Body();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link MyServiceResponse.Body.Car }
     *
     */
    public MyServiceResponse.Body.Car createMyServiceResponseBodyCar() {
        return new MyServiceResponse.Body.Car();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link MyServiceResponse }{@code >}}
     *
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.com/type", name = "serviceResponse")
    public JAXBElement<MyServiceResponse> createServiceResponse(MyServiceResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<MyServiceResponse>(_ServiceResponse_QNAME, MyServiceResponse.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **elementFormDefault="qualified"** for your model by creating a package-info.java and adding:

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.example.com/type", elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package mypkg;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

This will allow your regular XML, but not your "stripped" XML, to work.   The difference between the two, besides the "stripping" of the outer, wrapper elements, is the fact that your original XML has a default namespace set, while the stripped XML does not.

Comment: Thanks! This works and was the most appropriate solution for me as it requires the smallest possible change to the XSD that I use. I added elementFormDefault="qualified" to the `schema` element and that causes the maven-jaxb2-plugin that I use to generate a package-info.java file containing elementFormDefault="XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED".

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to use the `XMLStreamReader` in my application but for some events it is not working as expected. I have posted the question here if you get a chance please have a look and provide your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667516/stax-xmlstreamreader-check-for-the-next-event-without-moving-ahead

Answer (score 1):

Set the name attribute on the @XmlType annotation:

```
@XmlType(name = "Body", propOrder = {

})
public static class Body { ... }
```

and

```
@XmlType(name = "Car", propOrder = {

})
public static class Car { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works, but Scott's solution was a slightly better match for my situation.